# How can I print a list of structs that contain two members?

Tags: c++, xcode

I created a struct and put two member variables in it. Then initialized a list with the mentioned struct type.

```cpp
struct job {
    string name;
    int time;
};

list<job> jobList;

string line;
ifstream file("input.txt");  // the direction of my input file.
if (file.is_open()) {
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        string col1;
        int col2;
        istringstream ss(line);
        ss >> col1 >> col2;
        job a;
        a.name = col1;
        a.time = col2;

        jobList.push_back(a);
    }
}
```

Now I want to know, how can I print my `jobList`? Whatever I do, does not work and I get errors.

I used the following function to print my list contents:

```
for (auto v : jobList)
    std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

The error I get is:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'job')

I think that is because my struct has two variables (`name` and `time`) but I am not sure. The purpose of printing `jobList` is to make sure that I have created my list properly.

After printing, the output should be as follows:

```
MPL 3
JOB 1
CORE 50
DISK 10
CORE 150
DISK 0
CORE 100
DISK 0
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of how you print the list, and tell us the errors you get from it (copy-paste *as text* the full and complete build output). [Edit] your question to improve it. Also please try to keep consistent indentation in your code, that makes it easier to read and understand what's happening, as well as less chances of problems or errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with:

```
for (auto v : jobList)
    std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

is that `v` is a `job` structure, and you have no stream output operator overloaded for `job`.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Output the members one by one:

   ```
   for (auto const& v : jobList) {
       std::cout << v.name << " - " << v.time << '\n';
   }
   ```
2. Create an overloaded operator for outputting the structure:

   ```
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, job const& j)
   {
       return << v.name << " - " << v.time;
   }

   ...

   for (auto const& v : jobList) {
       std::cout << v << '\n';
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the individual struct members in your range-for loop:

```cpp
for (auto const& j : jobList)
    std::cout << j.name << ' ' << j.time << '\n';
```